# What is Consumer Group in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

What is Consumer Group in kafka? Please explain with a use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to explain it by describing the problem it solves.

So lets say you have a topic of messages that you want to consume, so you write a consumer. Each time you consume a message the offset will get updated so that your application knows that it's consumed and that it can consume the next one.
You realize that your consumer application can't handle all the incoming messages so you need to scale it out. Those two instances of your application don't want to consume messages that the other instance has consumed so they kinda want to share offsets, so they need to be in the same consumer group.

If you are writing a totally new application which also consumes from that same topic but needs to do so independently, it needs to be in its own consumer group so that it has it's own offsets